# ant, ivy, multiple projects and transitive dependencies

Tags: web-applications, ant, ivy

I have two projects, A and B, with B being a webapp.  Project B depends on A, so A's ivy.xml looks something like:

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
  <info organisation="com.confused" module="B" status="integration"/>    

  <dependencies>
    <!-- confused dependencies -->
    <dependency name="A" rev="latest.integration"/>

    <!-- 3rd party dependencies -->
    <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-core" rev="3.2.2.RELEASE"/>
    <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-jdbc" rev="3.2.2.RELEASE"/>
    <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-webmvc" rev="3.2.2.RELEASE"/>
  </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

something like that… and my A module looks like:

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
  <info organisation="com.confused" module="A" status="integration"/>    

  <dependencies>
    <dependency org="org.slf4j" name="slf4j-api" rev="1.7.5"/>
    <dependency org="ch.qos.logback" name="logback-classic" rev="1.0.11"/>
    <dependency org="ch.qos.logback" name="logback-core" rev="1.0.11"/>
  </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

All good… except:

When I build B, the lib directory is populated with the spring jars along with A.jar.  Fine and good, but if I want to 'deploy' my webapp, I need to copy these jars into WEB-INF/lib AND ALSO the logging jars that A depends on.  How do I get ant/ivy to 'resolve' jars as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't put the configuration your dependencies depend upon...

There is a sort of unofficial set of configurations that match up with Maven configurations that are used in the `ivy.xml` file. This [`ivy.template.xml`](https://github.com/qazwart/ivy.dir/blob/master/ivy.template.xml) file uses them, and I have that for my developers to base their `ivy.xml` files on.

What you need to do is map your configurations. Here's A's `ivy.xml` file:

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
    <info organisation="com.confused" module="A" status="integration"/>    

    <configurations>
        <configuration .../>
        <!-- These are the configurations from the ivy.template.xml file -->
    </configurations>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="org.slf4j" name="slf4j-api" rev="1.7.5"
            conf="compile->default"/>
        <dependency org="ch.qos.logback" name="logback-classic" rev="1.0.11"
            conf="compile->default"/>
        <dependency org="ch.qos.logback" name="logback-core" rev="1.0.11"
            conf="compile->default"/>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

Note the `conf` mappings! The `compile->default` says to use this for compile time, and for runtime dependencies. By mapping this to `default`, you are downloading not just this particular jar, but all transitive dependencies too.

Now, your `ivy.xml` for "B" will look like this:

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
    <info organisation="com.confused" module="B" status="integration"/>    

    <configurations>
        <configuration .../>
        <!-- These are the configurations from the ivy.template.xml file -->
    </configurations>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Don't forget the organisation field!-->
        <dependency org="com.confused" name="A" rev="latest.integration"
            conf="compile->default"/>

        <!-- 3rd party dependencies -->
        <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-core" rev="3.2.2.RELEASE"
            conf="compile->default"/>
        <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-jdbc" rev="3.2.2.RELEASE"
            conf="compile->default"/>
        <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-webmvc" rev="3.2.2.RELEASE"
            conf="compile->default"/>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

Your project A's jar, and its dependencies are simply just another set of jars that your project "B" depends up.

Of course, you have to [publish](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/publish.html) A's jar to your Ivy repository before "B" can use it.

Comment: Aye, I am a newb at this, and didn't fully understand configurations.  I still don't, but I'm gonna go figure it out now!  However, I figured out enough to prove you right, thank you very much!

Comment: Configurations are a way to _group_ your dependencies. For example, the standard is to have a "compile" configuration, a "test" configuration, and a "runtime" configuration. You could create a classpath using `<ivy:cachepath pathid="main.classpath conf="compile"/>`. That would only include the jars you need for compilation and not for testing or runtime. For your junit tests, you'd use something like `<ivy:cachepath pathid="test.classpath conf="test"/>`. The `a->b` mapping is a way to affect behavior and the _standard_ configs I have match Maven's configuration.